# Using events vs. directly calling parent application function from a child in Flex / Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, parent-child

If I need to call a specific function in the parent application from a child in a flex project, what's the best practice for this?  Would it be to dispatch a custom event from the child and have a listener call that function?  Or to directly call the function with FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OOP would say that Events are the way to go, since globals are anti-OOP and also since the event at least promotes some level of separation between the caller and the callee.

Comment: +1; I'd go even broader and say that "Globals are anti-encapsulation."  There are always trade-offs w/ any decision; but based on the original posters lack of details; we can't judge how bad accessing the topLevelApplication would be in this case.  As a general rule; don't do it.